# Webview text input has focus but no entered text shows

Tags: android, textview, android-webview

I have two text fields in a webview and when the user hits "Go"/"Enter" it moves focus to the next text field, however in doing so it no longer shows entered text despite having focus, is then too includes the first text field should one go back to it and grant focus. I've tried the following:

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.requestFocus();
    webView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    webView.setFocusable(true);
    webView.setHapticFeedbackEnabled(true);
    webView.setClickable(true);
```

Another note is that if I access the site from a browser it works fine, it's just when rendered by webview on a Nexus 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a Swiftkey issue, in that when disabling it in Settings and using the regular Google Keyboard instead the issue disappeared. Solution seems to be in updating the software: http://support.swiftkey.net/forums/116693-2-bug-reports/suggestions/3808949-phonegap-app